# Install mongo by CLI and for a project only inside project directory

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to install MongoDB only inside a directory through some sort of a script?

An idea is to use it as a dependency in a node.js project. After `npm install` on the project, npn would download mongo binaries, and install them into project's folder. Later this binaries could be accessible from node.js script which would control them like start the database. This should run on standard platforms (Win, Linux, Unix) and should be hidden from user.

I found a way for unattended install. But this would be installed for whole system and I'm not sure what changes It'll make to windows. Also this is platform dependent solution. I'd welcome some sort of unified node, like npm package.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-topology-manager) runs MongoDB servers, and is used for driver testing.

You'd need to download the binary which you could do via [m](https://github.com/aheckmann/m/). You could also do this [by hand](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/.evergreen/tools.rb).